# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable - tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I'm using tornado to get a list of domains, and iterate over those domains and run a process for each. I keep getting an error and I'm probably doing something simple wrong, but I can't figure it out.

Here's the traceback:

```
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 699, in render
    html = self.render_string(template_name, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 804, in render_string
    namespace = self.get_template_namespace()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 828, in get_template_namespace
    namespace.update(self.ui)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

And here's the code:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # product = self.get_argument('product-type', '')
        apikey = self.get_argument('apikey', '')
        domain = self.get_argument('domain', '')
        start = self.get_argument('start', '')
        end = self.get_argument('end', '')
        urls = domain.split(",")
        for u in urls:
            filePath = u + "_"  + start + "_"  + end + ".csv" 
            if apikey:
                results = max_concurrents(apikey, u, start, end, save_to=True)
                if filePath:
                    print filePath + 'valid'
                    self.render('index.html', data=filePath, domain=u, start=start, end=end)
            else:
                print filePath + 'invalid'
                self.render('index.html', data=filePath)

    def post(self):
        # product = self.get_argument('product-type', '')
        apikey = self.get_argument('apikey','')
        domain = self.get_argument('domain','')
        start = self.get_argument('start','')
        end = self.get_argument('end','')
        urls = domain.split(",")
        for u in urls:
            filePath = u + "_"  + start + "_"  + end + ".csv"
            print filePath
            print r
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that for is iterating over something that is None. I suspect `url` is None because of the for iteration.

Add some debugging to find out if `url` is None or has some value.

Comment: If `domain` was None, it would error out on `urls = domain.split(",")`

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `RequestHandler.render()` more than once; this finishes the request (and leaves the handler in an invalid state so you should generally just return after rendering). If you just want to concatenate all the template renderings, then you can call `self.write(self.render_string('index.html', ...))`.